# ERROR: Could not build wheels for fasttreeshap, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, shapely, shap

I am trying to install fasttreeshap in Sagemaker Studio with `!pip install fasttreeshap` and I get the following error:

```
error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fasttreeshap
Failed to build fasttreeshap
ERROR: Could not build wheels for fasttreeshap, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Things I have tried:

- Upgrading Pip
- Changing Python versions (Using 3.10.6 now)
- Installing with conda (Does not work, gets stuck on "solving enviroment")
- Everything else on google (There isn't much)

I am not familiar with gcc or how to install it and can't find much info on it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the instance that is assigned in the background by Sagemaker on which your code is hosted in Sagemaker Studio, it is a minimal version of the software and hence it does not have gcc and g++ installed which is usually part of full version.

I am assuming that the fasttreeshap python package requires the gcc and g++ packages to be installed.

I was facing the exact same issue while using python:3.9-slim docker image and running the following command, did the job for me:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc && apt-get install -y g++
```